# PHP MySQL Select max number of a row returns wrong number

Tags: php, mysql, sql, max

I have a database with a table 'customer'. In this row most of the customers have a value or number. I'm trying to get the highest number so the next one who registers will get the `highest number + 1`. The row `'usr' is varchar(255)`.

It was working with the following code:

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(usr) AS usr FROM customer";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$maxID   = $record['id'];
$nieuwID = $maxID + 1;
```

When I checked today I saw that the two latest registers both had number 10. When I checked my query it was returning 9. Why is it returning 9 and not 10? How can I fix this so my registers will have a unique number?

Comment: Why don't you just use Auto_increment instead of checking the last record and than update it..??

Comment: What happens if another user joins while you're doing this?

Comment: @Strawberry: Easy: there will be two (or more) users with the same number.

Comment: You are right @DeDevelopers, I'll have to edit my table structure. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usr should be integer. alter the table field structure

Answer (score 0):

Don't store numbers as character strings.  You are getting a string maximum.  For a numeric maximum, convert it to a number:

```
select max(usr + 0) as usr
from customer
```

But, as recommended in a comment, if you want an auto-incrementing field, use `auto_increment` and define the column to be a bona fide number.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `MAX()` with `varchar` field. if you want to use MAX() then you have to convert that field to `integer` instead of `varchar`.

Any operation which required addition, subtraction, avg, max etc. will not work on varchar field type

Answer (score 0):

OK firstly @DeDevelopers is right auto_incroment should be inforced to stop this from happening.

I strongly advise using this within you insert or update statement as even though the probability of duplicates is low it can happen ;)

I would also recommend re visiting your table architecture to support @DeDevelopers comment but if not then place somesort of error checking in place or unique key identifier against that table column

Comment: So you're assuming no deletions?!!